# How to create an instance for Floating only?

Tags: haskell

There is a class, for which I would like to define an instance.
It looks like this:

```
data MyValue a = MyValue a

class TestClass a where
    funcOne:: (Real b) => a b -> a b
    funcTwo:: (Real b) => a b -> a b -> a b


instance TestClass MyValue where
    funcOne (MyValue x) = MyValue (x*pi)
    funcTwo (MyValue x) (MyValue y) = MyValue (x*y)
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Floating b) arising from a use of `pi'
      from the context: Real b
```

I understand the error, but I don't know how should I solve it.

I can't change the `(Real b)` to `(Floating b)` because other instances should work with Integral types too. But `MyValue` makes sense with `Floating` only. Is it possible to tell the compiler, that the `instance TestClass MyValue` works only with `Floating`?

If it is not, then how is it possible to cast the result `x*pi` back to the same `Real` as the `x` parameter? It does not matter what happens if the type is for example Integral, because the `MyValue` does not make sense in that case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this, but you'll need to modify either that data type or the class.

- If `MyValue` in particular makes sense with Floating only then it makes perhaps sense to bake that constraint into its constructor.

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

  data MyValue :: * -> * where
    MyValue :: Floating a => a -> MyValue a
  ```

  This guarantees to any function accepting a `MyValue a` that `a` is actually a `Floating` instance, hence

  ```
    funcOne (MyValue x) = MyValue $ x*pi
  ```

  will then work.
- If this is a common theme, requiring a particular constraint on the contained type, then you can, instead of always requiring `Real`, make the constraint dependent on the instance:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds #-}
  import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

  class TestClass a where
    type Testable a b :: Constraint
    type Testable a b = Real b  -- default constraint
    funcOne:: Testable b => a b -> a b
    funcTwo:: Testable b => a b -> a b -> a b

  instance TestClass MyValue where
    type Testable MyValue b = Floating b
    funcOne (MyValue x) = MyValue $ x*pi
    ...
  ```
- But perhaps it's not the right decision to let `TestClass` deal with parameterised (`* -> *`) types in the first place, if you then need to artificially constrain the parametricity again. Why not instead do simply

  ```
  class TestClass q where
    funcOne :: q -> q
    funcTwo :: q -> q -> q

  instance Floating a => TestClass (MyValue a) where
    funcOne (MyValue x) = MyValue $ x*pi
    funcTwo (MyValue x) (MyValue y) = MyValue $ x*y
  ```

  That would seem cleaner to me anyway. If some of the methods do require access to the contained type, that's also possible with this approach, using an associated type family:

  ```
  class TestClass q where
    type ToTest q :: *
    ...

  instance Floating a => TestClass (MyValue a) where
    type ToTest (MyValue a) = a
    ...
  ```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of restricting `b` for that one instance. `TestClass` says that `funcOne` works for any `Real b`. If that is not the case for `MyValue`, then `MyValue` is not an instance of `TestClass`. Furthermore there is no way to cast from a `Floating` to `Real` without always loosing accuracy. The only way to get to the `Real` type would be `fromInteger`, but if you cast your type first to `Integer` you will always loose the fractional part.

The only thing you could do (that I am aware of) is using a different `MyValue` type that restricts `b` to always have a `Floating` constraint by using `GADTs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data MyValue' = Floating a => MyValue' a

instance TestClass MyValue' where
  -- Pattern matching on MyValue' brings the 'Floating' constraint into scope.
  funcOne (MyValue' x) = MyValue' $ x * pi
  ...
```

Now every time you have a value of type `MyValue' a` pattern matching on that value is proof that `a` is an instance of `Floating`.

Note that this approach fails if `TestClass` has a function that does not take a value of type `a`:

```
class TestClass a where
   ...
   pureTest :: Real b => b -> a b
```

Now in `pureTest` `b` does not have to be `Floating` and therefore `pureTest b = MyValue' b` would be a type error.